# request url in retrofit, that is hitting on server from code

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

How can I get what my api url is hitting in retrfit, I want to check what is my request url is generating in kotlin android.

Comment: You should use `Interceptors` with a custom `OkHttpClient`.

Comment: used already, how to get url formed with request parameters

Comment: The standard OkHttp logging interceptor should log the URL with request parameters to Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

In your Retrofit client you should add a specific interceptor to do this.

```kotlin
val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(Level.BODY)
val retrofitClient = Builder()
    .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
    .build()
```

Interceptors have a lot a *levels* to determine how verbose the logs should be, check [Retrofit's documentation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt) for further information